# Is it possible to go to higher level scope condition's else in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the exact same lines of code in the both `do something` section so I want to merge the two sections into one.
But I don't want to create a separate function for `do something`.

Is there a way to go to `condition A`'s else when it reaches `condition B`'s else?

```
if (conditionA)
    {
      //some code here
        if (conditionB)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want to create a new function? That's how one commonly puts together common code.

Comment: And just for your information, there are ways to *go to* some other place in a function. But no one would ever recommend that as it leads to code that is hard to read, understand, follow and maintain (read about *spaghetti code*).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because it's such a trivial code to make it a separate function. and also I don't want additional overhead by passing 6 arguments just to call a function.

Comment: Would it make sense to extract that code into a function?

Comment: @FreeNickname No, I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: Even if the code is trivial and you need to pass six arguments, it could still make sense. And if the code you have is inside a class, then perhaps you don't need to pass everything as arguments as they might be class members (and the function is a member function)? And don't forget to plan for the future, are you 100% sure the code will never be needed anywhere else in the whole lifetime of the program?

Comment: If all else fails use a goto.

Comment: And if you fall back to `goto`, ***document and comment it!***

Comment: There is a nice article by Donald E. Knuth where similar examples are discussed: Structured programming with go to statements // ACM Computing Surveys 6, 261 (1974).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if-else` is really just syntactic sugar for `goto`s. You can use an explicit `goto` here:

```
if (conditionA)
{
    //some code here
    if (conditionB)
    {

    } 
    else goto do_something;
}
else
{
    do_something: /*...*/;
}
```

This could/should be faster than adding another `if` check.

Alternatively, you can use an inlinable `static` function. There should be no performance difference if it does get inlined (and it won't piss off gotos-considered-harmful dogmatists).

(In my opinion, an occasional, clean, downward `goto` won't harm the readability of your code, but the dogmatism against `goto`s is strong (as evidenced by downvotes on this answer :D)).

Answer (score 5):

Jumping through code is definitely discouraged, if you really want to minimize the code then the only thing you can do is to rearrange the flow to better suit your needs, eg:

```
if (conditionA)
{
  some code 

  if (conditionB)
    do something else
}

if (!conditionA || !conditionB)
  do something
```

Answer (score 5):

If you (as indicated in the comments) don't want to create a function that you need to pass 6 arguments, then you *could* use a lambda like this:

```
const auto do_something = [&] { /* do stuff with captured reference variables */ };
if (conditionA) {
    // some code here
    if (conditionB) {
        // stuff
    } else {
        do_something();
    }
} else {
     do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that there is no code after `//do something`, You can use a pattern such as

```
if (conditionA)
{
    //some code here
    if (conditionB)
    {
         //do something else
         return;
    }
}
//do something
```

However a clearer pattern would be to encapsulate `//do something` into a separate function.

Comment: the whole code is inside a `for` loop so it should not return.

Comment: @ZackLee Then `continue;`.

Comment: @ZackLee Just replace the `return;` with `continue;`

Answer (score 3):

To answer what you are asking in the title: Yes, it is possible. There are at least three ways I can think of:

1. Using `goto`'s (highly discouraged)
2. Putting "do something" code in a function (perhaps inline for performance) *(may result to cleaner code)*
3. Reformatting your if/else statements and merging your conditions as demonstrated in other answers. The rationale is to group the code segments that appear twice (by unifying logical expressions using operators). *(I would prefer this way if the code is not that large or if it has high dependencies with other parts)*

Comment: It shouldn't be a `else if`. Consider if `A` is true and `B` is false here. `some code` will not be run even though it should.

Comment: Nice catch, I removed the code snippet, as when tried to fix it, I understood that it does not provide anything new compared to other answers

Answer (score 2):

I would change conditions and rearrange the code a bit.

```
if (!conditionA || (conditionA && !conditionB))
    do_something();
else if (conditionA) {
    some_code_here();
    if (conditionB)
        // Your `if(conditionB)` section goes here.
}
```

Another possibility (one I think is often preferable) is to combine the conditions into a single variable, then use a case statement for the combinations:

```
unsigned cond = ConditionA | (ConditionB << 1);

enum { neither, A, B, both};

switch (cond) { 
     neither: // Both A and B were false;
     A: // Only A was true;
     B: // Only B was true;
     both: // both A and B were true;
}
```

Then when you want the same code executed for two conditions, you just let normal switch fall-through happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it up into cthulhu loop and use `break`:

```
for(;;) // executed only once
{
    if (conditionA)
    {
        //some code here
        if(conditionB)
        {
            //  some more code here
            break; // for(;;)
        }
    }
    //do something
    break; // for(;;)
}
```

Comment: @PSkocik What do you mean?

Comment: OP's original code has the structure of `if(conditionA) { if(conditionB){}else DO_SOMETHING(); }else{ DO_SOMETHING(); }`. I don't think you can make a `break` jump into an unrelated else branch.

Comment: @PSkocik `break` jumps out of the outer loop, not into unrelated else branch.

Comment: Yup. My point exactly.  But you need to jump into the `else` branch to keep the semantics of OP's original code while deduplicating the do something part. (like with `if(conditionA){ if(conditionB){/*..*/}else goto do_something; }else{ do_something: /*...*/; }`). I don't think it can be straightforwardly done without goto, a seperate function, or extra if checks.

Comment: @PSkocik This code does exactly the same thing as OP's code. If `conditionA` is false it executes only `do something` part; if `conditionA` is true but `conditionB` is false it executes `some code here` and then `do something`; if both conditions are true it executes `some code here` and `some more code here`. If you think there is mismatch somewhere then please point exact combinations of conditions leading to it.

Comment: You're correct. My apologies. (I already upvoted but got confused).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more alegant then use `for(;;)` (VTT answer, which I upwoted)

```
do 
{
   if(conditionA )
   { 
      //some code here
      if(conditionB) 
      { 
         //some code
          break;
      }  
   } 
   // do something
} while(0);
```